# How to test if a window is open remotely in powershell

Tags: powershell

The problem I'm trying to solve is a process, in this case acrobat is getting hung in the background. I want to close it if there are no actual windows of adobe present.

This code needs to be able to run through a remote command. The code I have works locally, but because of the way powershell detects windows it won't work remotely. Any ideas?

```
function stop-adobe {
    param ([string]$computername)
    Invoke-Command $computername -scriptblock {
        #tests to see if the window is open and returns a value of true or false
        $test = Get-Process | where {$_.MainWindowTitle} | where {$_.ProcessName -like "acrobat"}

        If ($test) {
            msg * "Adobe is running perfectly, please inform the person you are on the phone with of this so that we can further troubleshoot"
        }
        else {
            #kills the process since it does not have an active window
            Stop-Process -name acrobat
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a scheduled task, set it to run only when the user is logged on (i.e. interactively); it should be able to run this window-detecting code. Have it write its conclusions elsewhere. Your main script is then creating that task, starting it, waiting for it and checking the output. This sounds convoluted, but essentially the remote PowerShell command is running in a non-interactive session, completely isolated from whatever the user is doing, so you need to get *something* running in that other session.

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are you on?  `Get-Process` has an `-IncludeUserName` switch although I'm not entirely sure when that was introduced.

Comment: You could use WMI to get the process owner regardless of PS version. The issue is determining if the process has a window open or not and that can only be done from code running in the user's context.

Comment: I think Jeroen Moster's comment on PowerShell running in a non-interactive session is important here. When you run an "Invoke-Command" on a remote computer, it is not running as the current user that is logged into that computer. It is running as if powershell was launched by your account on that computer, that is why it's failing to run. A scheduled task that could run as the currently logged is a solution but maybe not a good one, you would need to set this up on every computer that needs the ability to run this script.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the feedback I guess it's just easier to ask if they have it open then kill it as opposed to running a psjob on thousands of computers.

Answer (score -1):

You may change a bit and try

```
 function stop-adobe {
param ([string]$computername)
Invoke-Command $computername -scriptblock {
    #tests to see if the window is open and returns a value of true or false
    $test = Get-Process | where {$_.MainWindowTitle} | where {$_.ProcessName -like "*acro*"}

    If ($test) {
        msg * "Adobe is running perfectly, please inform the person you are on the phone with of this so that we can further troubleshoot"
    }
    else {
        #kills the process since it does not have an active window
         Stop-Process -Id $test.Id
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This doesn't take into account the problem that causes the program to not work. It must be ran as the user logged into the computer, the script itself is not the problem.